# BaseJQueryEventObject, JQueryEventObject, etc are deprecated. What do we replace it with?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, typescript

When you migrate from jQuery v2 to jQuery v3, interfaces like BaseJQueryEventObject on types definitions are deprecated.

What is the replacement on code?

For example, with angularjs, we have functions like this:

```
public keyDown($event: JQueryEventObject) {
    alert ($event.keyCode);
}
```

And we receive a message like this:

```
ERROR: 18:28  deprecation  JQueryEventObject is deprecated.
```

Here is the new type definition: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/7a9ecd61d02e715adf369b191571007bd1a7c572/types/jquery/index.d.ts#L7546

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem but i solved it

```
public keyDown($event: KeyboardEvent) {
    alert ($event.keyCode);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

I am not sure about angular but, using latest Typescript and JQuery I changed my function signature to:

```
public keyDown($event: JQuery.Event) {
    alert ($event.keyCode);
}
```

Comment: This is the answer that saved me when updating from JQuery 2.4 to 3.2

Comment: Doing this I get TS2702 JQuery only refers to a type but is being used as a namespace here